# Angular Material 2 md-menu position

Tags: angular, angular-material2

for some reason, the md-menu seems to always appear on the left of the triggering element.

See [this plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/ZhI4rTdGV3JfMrAtGs8u/) for an example.

```
<button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu" style="width: 300px">
   BUTTON
</button>

<md-menu #appMenu="mdMenu">
  <button md-menu-item> Settings </button>
  <button md-menu-item> Help </button>
</md-menu>
```

Is there a way to control that?

I would like the menu to appear in the middle of the button, or where the click was made.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your plnkr link is not opening.

Answer (score 1):

`md-menu` provides only positon `before` and `after` for `positionX`. So, there's no documented way of moving the menu panel.

As a work around, if you know the position of your trigger element, you can add some css override to move the menu panel.

Here's an example:

css:

```
>>> .cdk-overlay-pane {
      left: 100px !important;
    }
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/jwt36RQiqnNMPl2lWScW?p=preview)

Comment: As a warning, this will affect all overlays (dialogs, selects, all menus). You can add custom classes to md-menu and add global styles to move it around [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qdbiAABVuvx2IDTM4v4B?p=preview)